# Date input in sql string from variable

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have this code but it won't read my date. I tried putting "#" & variable & "#".

```
Private Sub Comando77_Click()
Dim nvoto As Single
Dim giorno As Date
Dim strsql As String
Dim codice As Integer
Dim vmateria As String

codice = Val(InputBox("inserire la matricola"))
giorno = InputBox("inserire la data")
nvoto = Val(InputBox("inserire il nuovo voto"))

If nvoto <> 0 Then
    strsql = "Update Verifiche Set Voto=" & nvoto & " where Studente=" & codice & _
      " and Data=" & VBA.Format(giorno, " dd/mm/yyyy")
    DoCmd.RunSQL (strsql)
    Me.Refresh
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, an InputBox always returns text, so you must convert the input to a date value. Then format that as a proper string expression to concatenate with the SQL. Also, format your Single value correctly:

```
Private Sub Comando77_Click()

    Dim nvoto As Single
    Dim giorno As Date
    Dim strsql As String
    Dim codice As Integer
    Dim vmateria As String

    codice = Val(InputBox("inserire la matricola"))
    giorno = DateValue(InputBox("inserire la data"))
    nvoto = CSng(InputBox("inserire il nuovo voto"))

    If nvoto <> 0 Then
        strsql = "Update Verifiche Set Voto=" & Str(nvoto) & " where Studente=" & codice & " and Data=#" & VBA.Format(giorno, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#"
        DoCmd.RunSQL strsql
        Me.Refresh
    End If

End Sub
```